# How to import and create my class from my module?

Tags: python, python-3.3, python-module

I am creating a module, it has the classes:

```
class LogLevel():

    Info    = 1
    Warn    = 2
    Error   = 3


class FalconPeer():

    def __init__(self, port=37896, log_level=LogLevel.Info):
        self._port = port
        self._log_level = log_level
```

In the folder structure:

```
+---PyFalconUDP
    |   CHANGES.txt
    |   LICENSE.txt
    |   MANIFEST.in
    |   README.txt
    |   setup.py
    |   
    +---falconudp
        |   enums.py
        |   falconpeer.py
        |   tree.txt
        |   __init__.py
        |   
        +---test
        |       test_location.py
        |       test_utils.py
        |       __init__.py
```

But running Python in the PyFalconUDP folder I cannot import and use my classes - how do I create a `FalconPeer`?

```
    Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
    tel)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import falcondup.FalconPeer
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named 'falcondup'
    >>> import falconudp.FalconPeer
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named 'falconudp.FalconPeer'
    >>> import falconudp
    >>> a = FalconUDP()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    NameError: name 'FalconUDP' is not defined
    >>> a = falconudp.FalconPeer()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FalconPeer'
    >>> from falconudp import FalconPeer
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: cannot import name FalconPeer
    >>>
```

Comment: from your interpreter shell, can you do this for me, import os  and os.getcwd()

Comment: after importing os it output: 'C:\\Dev\PyFalconUDP', i.e. the directory I started the interpreter in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Break down your details:**

```
Pkg : falcondup
Module: falconpeer
Class : FalconPeer
```

**Import using the module name:**

```
import falcondup.falconpeer
```

**Create an object using the full path till the class name:**

```
obj = falcondup.falconpeer.FalconPeer()
```

Once you created the obj, you can call all the method inside the class.

**Calling method inside class:**

```
obj.method_name()
```

**And if you want to access class attribute, by using the class name.**

```
falcondup.falconpeer.LogLevel.Info
falcondup.falconpeer.LogLevel.Warn
falcondup.falconpeer.LogLevel.Error
```

If you want to use inside : **class_name.class_var_name**

**Another scenerio:**

if you LogLevel class are in different file which mean different modules, then you need to import that module than you can access it.

Comment: aha! getting further, now I get LogLevel is not defined (the LogLevel class is in enums.py), do you know how I can access the class attribute from FalconPeer?

Comment: I still get NameError: name 'falconudp' is not defined if FalconPeer's __init__ takes (log_level = falconudp.falconpeer.LogLevel.Info)

Comment: are you running from some main script or from the interpreter ?

Comment: I am just running import falconudp.falconpeer from the interpreter with code as above except FalconPeer's __init__ function changed as in previous comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46986/discussion-between-yopy-and-markmnl)

Answer (score 1):

To import something from your falconudp module, it should be in the global namespace of `__init__.py`.

So the class declarations should either:

1. be inside `__init__.py`, or
2. Be inside falconpeer.py, and you should also have `import falconpeer` inside `__init__.py`